# Fibonacci sequence

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

Given an integer $n ≥ 1$, let $f_n$ be the number of lists whose elements all equal $1$ or $2$ and add up to $n−1$. For example $f_1 = 1 = f_2$ because only the empty list ($0$ ones and $0$ twos) sums to $0$ and only a single one sums to $1$. The lists $1,2;\, 2,1;\, 1,1,1$ show us that $f_4 = 3$.

> (a) Show that $f_{n+2} = f_{n+1} + f_n$ and hence that $f_1, f_2,...$ is the Fibonacci sequence.
>
> (b) How many lists of ones and twos are there that add up to $10$ and contain $3$ twos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a list of $1$s and $2$s adding up to $n-1$, we can append a $2$ to the end of that list to get one adding up to $n+1$. Given a list of $1$s and $2$s adding up to $n$, we can append a $1$ to the end of that list to get one adding up to $n+1$. The lists obtained in this way are uniquely determined by the lists we started from. (Why?) Hence, $$f_{n+2}\geq f_{n+1}+f_n.$$ On the other hand, given a list of $1$s and $2$s adding up to $n+1$, removing the last number on the list will give us one adding up to $n$ or $n-1$. Hence, $$f_{n+2}\leq f_{n+1}+f_n,$$ and so $$f_{n+2}=f_{n+1}+f_n.$$

---

A list of $1$s and $2$s adding up to $10$ and having $3$ $2$s will necessarily have $7$ total entries. (Why?) Such a list is moreover completely determined by the placement of the $2$s. Since there are $7$ spots and $3$ $2$s to place, there are $\binom{7}{3}=35$ such lists.

Comment: can you please help me solve this  Consider the ﬁnite sum
 S=1+2x+3x^(2)+4x^(3)+____+nx^(n-1)

Calculate S − xS and hence give a closed expression for S?

Comment: The site will only allow you to ask $6$ questions in a given $24$-hour period. If you wait until tomorrow, you can post that as a question.

Answer (score 2):

The first question has appeared several times on MSE.

For the second, there is some ambiguity: Do we mean contain (i) **exactly** $3$ twos or (ii) **at least** $3$ twos?

For (i), if there are exactly $3$ twos, then there must be $4$ ones, a total of $7$ digits.  The **locations** of the twos can be chosen in $\dbinom{7}{3}$ ways. After the location of the twos is determined, the ones have to occupy the remaining slots. Calculate: there are $35$ choices.

For interpretation (ii), we are allowed to have $3$ twos, or $4$, or $5$. The analysis is much the same as for interpretation (i), except that we get $\dbinom{7}{3}+\dbinom{6}{4}+\dbinom{5}{5}$.

Comment: can you please help me solve this                                                               Consider the ﬁnite sum
 S=1+2x+3x^(2)+4x^(3)+____+nx^(n-1)

Calculate S − xS and hence give a closed expression for S?

Comment: To do it in the style they ask for, note that $xS=x+2x^2+3x^3+\cdots +nx^n$. Now calculate $S-xS$. This is $(1+2x+3x^2+\cdots+nx^{n-1})-(x+2x^2+\cdots+(n-1)x^{n-1}+nx^n)$. Look at the terms. We get a $1$. Also a $2x-x$. Also a $3x^2-2x^2$, and so on. We end up with (check it) $1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^{n-1}-nx^n$. The first part is a finite geometric series, with sum $\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$, if $x\ne 1$. So we end up with $(1-x)S=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}-nx^n$. Divide by $1-x$ to get $S$.

Comment: @Aka: You are welcome. But in general I would prefer not to type much mathematics in comments, the editing facilities are poor, the length severely limited.

Answer (score 1):

(a) should come from the fact that when you delete the final element of a list which sums to $n+2$ you may end up with a list that sums to $n+1$ (if you deleted a $1$) or to $n$ (if you deleted a $2$).

As to (b), you are talking of lists of length $7$, containing four $1$ and three $2$. This should be [stars and bars (Theorem Two)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) which yields
$$
\binom{4 + 4 - 1}{4} = \binom{7}{4} = 35.
$$
That is, you have to put your four $1$ in four bins (separated by the three $2$), and some bin may be empty.

**PS** I have read the post of @AndréNicolas. I have intended question (b) as requiring *exactly* three $2$.

Comment: can you please help me solve this? Consider the ﬁnite sum
 S=1+2x+3x^(2)+4x^(3)+____+nx^(n-1)

Calculate S − xS and hence give a closed expression for S?

Comment: @Aka, please post a separate question if you wish. Comments are not the place to start new questions.

Comment: i tried posting but the website didnt accept my question post

Answer (score 0):

Let $L_k$ the set of lists  whose elements all equal $1$ or $2$ and add up to $k$. You want to show that $f_n=|L_n|$.
 Note that $\ell\in L_{n-2}\Rightarrow \text{append}(\ell,2)\in L_n$ and $\ell \in L_{n-1}\Rightarrow \text{append}(\ell,1)\in L_n$. Conclude that $|L_{n-2}|+|L_{n-1}|\leq |L_{n}|$...